# Knockout js: what is the proper way to trade out an image for text

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a text area in which I would variously like to have either: "Loading..." along with a little loading gif, or the actual text from the backend.

I can use `data-bind=text:...`  to trade "Loading..." for some other text, but what is the proper way to get the gif in there?

Comment: Use the `if binding`? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick solution is to add "visible" or "if" binding to the element containing gif, so that it will be shown only when the condition is true.